# Convert an Unix timestamp to good GMT date PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix, gmt

I want to get the FRENCH GMT DATE from an Unix timestamp.
In my database, i saved the date in GMT+0 then i  get the timestamp of this date and want to display the date with the good GMT+2

My timestamp is :1461857633 from database and it's equal to : 29/04/2016 12:27:11
And now i want to display this date with local GMT.
So i did this :

```
$timestamp = 1461857633;
$format = 'd/m/Y H:i:s';
$res = date($format, $timestamp);
echo $res;
```

and i have the same date 29/04/2016 12:27:11 where as my timezone is well 'Europe/Paris' 
Normaly i should to have this date  :  29/04/2016 14:27:11

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');`?

Answer (score 0):

$timestamp = 1461857633;

$effectiveDate = strtotime("+120 minutes", $timestamp);

$format = 'd/m/Y H:i:s';
$res = date($format, $effectiveDate);

echo $res;

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$HUTC = date("h");

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
$HParis = date("h");

$diff = $HParis - $HUTC;

$timestamp = 1461857633;
$timestamp = 1461857633 + $diff * 60 * 60;
$format = 'd/m/Y H:i:s';
$res = date($format,$timestamp);
echo $res;
```

This will work both summer and winter time

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add 2 hours to the timestamp or you can create a DateTime object and modify it by adding 2 hours to it:

```
$timestamp = 1461857633 + 2 * 60 * 60;
```

or

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimestamp(1461857633)->modify('+2 hours');
echo $dateTime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

or, another solution would be to calculate the seconds between the timezone you want to convert to and the Greenwich time zone (which is GMT+0) like:

```
$greenwichTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('Greenwich Mean Time');
$parisTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris');
$dateTimeGreenwich = new DateTime('now', $greenwichTimeZone);

$seconds = $parisTimeZone->getOffset($dateTimeGreenwich);
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimestamp(1461857633 + $seconds);
echo $dateTime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should remove the part about adding two hours from your answer. In winter time it's only one hour difference to GMT.

Comment: Oh.. didn't see that both parts of the answer was about two hours plus.